# How to open another Form from current Form?

Tags: forms, vb6

Our first form is the LOG IN form..how can I open to the next form after logging in?

Comment: Have any of our responses managed to help you with your question?

Answer (score 11):

In your log-in form, I assume you perform your validation inside of the `Click` event method for a button control. So you would have something like:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    If ValidatePassword(txtPassword.Text) Then
        ' The password is correct, so show the main form and close the login form
        MainForm.Show
        Unload Me
    Else
        ' The password is incorrect, so leave this form on screen
        MsgBox "Invalid password entered!", vbError
        txtPassword.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

The two interesting features of this code are:

1. The `Show` method, which you call on the form object that you want to show.
   In this case, it will probably be your main form—replace `MainForm` with whatever it is called.
2. The `Unload` statement, which closes and destroys the specified form.
   In this case, `Me` refers to the login form since you're finished with it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need call `Show` on the form which needs to be displayed post login form. You can read more about [Understanding Forms and form events](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-forms-vb6-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to avoid trying to open a logon Form as the first Form.

Instead let the main Form be first, and in its Load event Show your logon Form as a modal dialog.  This can be done revealing the main Form first by doing a Show on it.  Example based on the standard template "Log in Dialog" Form with some code changes:

**frmMain.frm**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim Control As Control

    Show
    frmLogin.Show vbModal, Me
    With frmLogin
        txtSuccess.Text = CStr(.LoginSucceeded)
        If .LoginSucceeded Then
            'Proceed normally, perhaps after capturing
            'the User Name, etc.
            txtUserName.Text = .User
            txtPassword.Text = .Password
        Else
            'Do "Unload Me" or disable all controls
            'as shown here, etc.
            For Each Control In Controls
                On Error Resume Next
                Control.Enabled = False
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next
        End If
    End With
    Unload frmLogin
End Sub
```

**frmLogin.frm**

```
Option Explicit

Public LoginSucceeded As Boolean
Public User As String
Public Password As String

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    LoginSucceeded = False
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    'Check for correct password, hard-coded here.
    If txtPassword.Text = "password" Then
        LoginSucceeded = True
        User = txtUserName.Text
        Password = txtPassword.Text
        Hide
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Password, try again!", , "Login"
        With txtPassword
            .SetFocus
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Modal dialogs are probably a better solution. My answer assumed what the asker already had, which isn't always the best approach!

Comment: This would not need to be done from Form_Load either, it could as easily be the result of a menu or button to initiate logon... assuming there is much point in having the Form visable and active before a logon.  Perhaps logons with different credentials for serial sessions during one run.